# ControllerActionInvoker & asp.net core Razor Pages

Tags: razor, razor-pages

The `ControllerActionInvoker` work with MVC controller to select an action. Is there something equivalent to choose a Razor Page between two pages?

I have two Razor Pages `RazorPage1.cshtml` and `RazorPage2.cshtml`. I want to use a logic to load either `RazorPage1` or `RazorPage2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can render then as Partial view base on you conditional logic in parent view

Or

In controller you can write a conditional logic to render different view based on view name